# Javascript: How to fire Onclick Event of button before Onchange event of another textbox which is on same page

Tags: javascript

In my page I have a Textbox having Onchange event and a button which is having Onclick button.
Whenever user types any text inside Textbox and then immediately clicks on button, first Onchange event of Textbox gets fired and then onclick event of Button gets executed.

Is there any way where I can fire Onclick event before Onchange, or atleast in Onchange event nothing should happen if clicking on button  caused Onchange event.

I tried different things but still no success.

Comment: <input id="txtName" type="text" onchange="CallOnchange();" />
                                    <button type="button" name="cmdADD" onclick="CallOnclick();">Add</button>

Comment: Sounds like you have to rethink your logic. What are you doing on those events?

Comment: Don't bind your change function to the change event. Execute it at the end of the click handler.

Comment: I am using Ajax HTML Editor whose value is getting saved in database by using Ajax Callback for that OnClientChnage event is used.Inside OnClientChnage a callback method is getting called for saving data.It works fine if after changing text of editor, user click anywhere in page but problem comes when user clicks on any buttons(Bold,Underline etc) present on Toolbar of editor, in this case OnClientChange should "NOT" get fired or atleast inside it we should be able to "avoid" Callback request for saving.

Comment: <ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender ID="heeReviewComment" OnClientChange="onContentsChange"

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, I don't know why would you want to do that, but here is an alternative of what you want to achieve:

Javascript

```
var oldValue = null;

function onClickCall(value) {
  if(value != oldValue) {
    onChangeCall(value);
    oldValue = value;
  }
}

function onChangeCall(value) {
  // do something here
  alert(value);
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="myTextInput" />
<input type="button" onclick="onClickCall(document.getElementById('myTextInput').value)" />
```

Comment: @Matei.. I am using Ajax HTML Editor whose value is getting saved in database by using Ajax Callback for that OnClientChnage event is used.Inside OnClientChnage a callback method is getting called for saving data.It works fine if after changing text of editor, user click anywhere in page but problem comes when user clicks on any buttons(Bold,Underline etc) present on Toolbar of editor, in this case OnClientChange should "NOT" get fired or atleast inside it we should be able to "avoid" Callback request for saving.